# Multiple servers share storage space

Tags: linux, webserver, ubuntu-server, haproxy

I tried to build a simple hosting system with only one server, but now I would create a simple network with 2 servers and a load balancer.

I was wondering if is it possibile that 2 different servers share their internal storage space (because the example of site is a file storage and I upload files on server). I need a solution without another external storage, I would that every server has personal storage and share the space where I upload files.

Comment: I mean simply, for example save with php a file with  move_uploaded_file function on server A. When user visit website and request is performed by server B, user could view all files that he have uploaded (no matter whether on server A or server B, all linked files).

Answer (score 0):

Your question seems to jump between sharing *Disk Space* and *Memory* - files go on *Disk Space*, but you ask for *Memory*.

Both is possible, but it is a very different thing.

If you want to share *Disk Space*, you can use any of a variety of solution, for example a NAS drive (Network Attached Storage) - both servers just connect the same network disk and use it. There are more sophisticated solutions, SAN disk, etc., but they are more costly and complex (and offer better performance).

If you want to share internal *Memory*, you can for example in VirtualBox run the guests = servers on the same host, and set the virtual machines to do that (google *'virtual box memory ballooning'*). That is a rarer concept and they obviously need to run on the same hardware, which in turn needs to have quite a lot of memory, but it works just fine.